# Cocoa Can I Hide / Show an NSTextField / NSSecureTextField

Tags: macos, nstextfield

Is there a way to turn secureTextField on and off in Cocoa? (OSX). I'd like users to have the option to see their passwords.

In iOS, I can do something like [textField setSecureTextEntry:YES];

I found  [secureTextField setEchoBullets] but that's not what I want.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me works perfectly to have two different cells in the same NSTextField and switch between them.

```
void osedit_set_password_mode(OSEdit *edit, const bool_t password_mode)
{
    OSXEdit *ledit = (OSXEdit*)edit;
    cassert_no_null(ledit);
    if (password_mode == TRUE)
    {
        if ([ledit cell] == ledit->cell)
        {
            [ledit->scell setStringValue:[ledit->cell stringValue]];
            [ledit->scell setBackgroundColor:[ledit->cell backgroundColor]];
            [ledit->scell setTextColor:[ledit->cell textColor]];
            [ledit->scell setAlignment:[ledit->cell alignment]];
            [ledit->scell setFont:[ledit->cell font]];
            [ledit setCell:ledit->scell];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ([ledit cell] == ledit->scell)
        {
            [ledit->cell setStringValue:[ledit->scell stringValue]];
            [ledit->cell setBackgroundColor:[ledit->scell backgroundColor]];
            [ledit->cell setTextColor:[ledit->scell textColor]];
            [ledit->cell setAlignment:[ledit->scell alignment]];
            [ledit->cell setFont:[ledit->scell font]];
            [ledit setCell:ledit->cell];
        }
    }
}
```

The interface

```
@interface OSXEdit : NSTextField 
{
    @public
    NSTextFieldCell *cell;
    NSSecureTextFieldCell *scell;
}
@end
```

The constructor

```
OSEdit *osedit_create()
{
    OSXEdit *edit = nil;
    NSTextFieldCell *cell = nil;
    edit = [[OSXEdit alloc] initWithFrame:NSZeroRect];
    cell = [edit cell];
    [cell setEditable:YES];
    [cell setSelectable:YES];
    [cell setBordered:YES];
    [cell setBezeled:YES];
    [cell setDrawsBackground:YES];
    edit->cell = [cell retain];
    edit->scell = [[NSSecureTextFieldCell alloc] init];
    [edit->scell setEchosBullets:YES];
    [edit->scell setEditable:YES];
    [edit->scell setSelectable:YES];
    [edit->scell setBordered:YES];
    [edit->scell setBezeled:YES];
    [edit->scell setDrawsBackground:YES];
    return (OSEdit*)edit;
}
```

And destructor

```
void osedit_destroy(OSEdit *edit)
{
    OSXEdit *ledit = (OSXEdit*)edit;
    [ledit->cell release];
    [ledit->scell release];
    [ledit release];
}
```

Comment: What is the class OSEdit? Also NSTextField does not seem to have a member "cell".

Comment: OSEdit is just a C-wrapper on OSXEdit to be able to use Cocoa objects in pure-C applications. OSXEdit derives from NSTextField and implements two cells: Normal (it's own cell) and Secure. There is only one active cell at each moment, but OSXEdit keeps pointers to both. The target is toggle between Normal and Secure state as if it were a property of NSTextField. In Windows this is possible. `SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SETPASSWORDCHAR, (WPARAM)L'•', (LPARAM)0);`

Answer (score 3):

I think you will need to have both an `NSTextField` and an `NSSecureTextField`.  You could put them in a tabless `NSTabView` to make it a little easier to switch between them.

Comment: That's very strange. But thanks - I got the same answer on the Cocoa mailing list..

Comment: I realized I could do this: 1. use just an NSTextField, and 2. if (hide me) textField.stringValue = @"******"; Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I think this is the safer solution: http://www.mikeabdullah.net/kspasswordfield.html

Comment: @DavidDelMonte, what you're missing is that some people will want to type the password in the secure field, and never show the plain text.

Comment: Interesting, Mike Abdullah's solution is similar in concept, but swaps the cell rather than the whole control.  I'm not sure why it's "safer" though.

Comment: I meant, safer than mine. However, I am not masking the textfield, I'm storing the data somewhere as the user types it in, but the text representation really has nothing to do with that. Ie, whatever they type in, they would get 8 bullets/asterisks..

Answer (score -1):

I have found a simple solution by creating a custom font showing a bullet for all character.
By this way, I just need to switch between the system font and my bullets font to show/hide a password.

I've found an easy way for creating the bullets font on the site https://www.glyphrstudio.com/online/