# Can an NSSecureTextField show plaintext?

Tags: swift, nstextfield

***NB: I've read [this question on a similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640093/cocoa-can-i-hide-show-an-nstextfield-nssecuretextfield), but that was two years ago and for Objective-C.***

I have an `NSSecureTextField` in which the user enters some text. At a certain point in my code, I would like to allow the `NSSecureTextField` to display the exact text the user entered previously when an `NSButton` is triggered.

Sample code below:

```
@IBOutlet var secureText: NSSecureTextField!    // secure text field, with text

@IBAction func switchSecureDisplay(sender: NSButton) {

    // here's where I would like to switch secure display to normal plaintext display.
    // unfortunately, no such method exists
    secureText.displayPlainText()

}
```

Is it feasible to implement such a method `displayPlainText()`? If not, are there possible alternative workarounds?

Comment: @HAS `NSSecureTextField` has no such property, I used it as an example for my target

Comment: You're right, sorry!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cocoa Can I Hide / Show an NSTextField / NSSecureTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21640093/cocoa-can-i-hide-show-an-nstextfield-nssecuretextfield)

Answer (score 1):

Someone else also asked this question two years ago and there was an accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21640804/6328387).

Since you marked this [swift](/questions/tagged/swift), you should know this is possible using a `UITextField` and toggling the `secureTextEntry` property on that object.

Comment: `` has no such function `secureTextEntry` as far as I'm aware, though indeed `UITextField` does.

Comment: Looking at the documentation for `NSSecureTextField`, it uses `NSSecureTextFieldCell` to modify the text field behavior. There's an `echosBullets` Boolean property which might resolve your issue. I'd try it out but I'm on Xcode 7 now.

Comment: Note that the `echosBullets` property may only change what is echoed when a character is typed. If clearing the flag still shows 'bullets' in the textfield, you might try to get and then set the field value.  Otherwise, the only workaround may be to use two fields, NSSecureTextField and NSTextField, placed one on top of the other (as mentioned in the link) and programmatically show/hide the appropriate field.

Comment: @bbabin: I strongly considered this approach in an app I'm developing, but decided against it since it was inherently insecure — a malicious keylogger (even without running as root) could capture keystrokes on plain text fields. So if the user typed say, an encryption password, into the `NSTextField` the keylogger could capture it. `NSSecureTextField` has system-level protections against this.

Comment: Related tech notes on secure input: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2150/_index.html

Answer (score -1):

if you don't have inbuilt try this
store the text in a variable temporary and display the text in text field When clicked button